# Possible to make the slider responsive according to browser size?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

[Jsfiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/q1sod9zp/1/)

HTML

```
    <section class="wrap row">
  <div class="container">
     <div class="slider">
      <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-lg-2">
        <img src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/f/5/6/f/1352194206656819167small_ragdoll_kitten-md.png" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-lg-2">
        <img src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/f/5/6/f/1352194206656819167small_ragdoll_kitten-md.png" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-lg-2">
        <img src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/f/5/6/f/1352194206656819167small_ragdoll_kitten-md.png" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-lg-2">
        <img src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/f/5/6/f/1352194206656819167small_ragdoll_kitten-md.png" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-lg-2">
        <img src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/f/5/6/f/1352194206656819167small_ragdoll_kitten-md.png" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-lg-2">
        <img src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/f/5/6/f/1352194206656819167small_ragdoll_kitten-md.png" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-lg-2">
        <img src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/f/5/6/f/1352194206656819167small_ragdoll_kitten-md.png" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-lg-2 ">
        <img src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/f/5/6/f/1352194206656819167small_ragdoll_kitten-md.png" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-lg-2">
        <img src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/f/5/6/f/1352194206656819167small_ragdoll_kitten-md.png" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-lg-2 ">
        <img src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/f/5/6/f/1352194206656819167small_ragdoll_kitten-md.png" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-lg-2">
        <img src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/f/5/6/f/1352194206656819167small_ragdoll_kitten-md.png" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-lg-2">
        <img src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/f/5/6/f/1352194206656819167small_ragdoll_kitten-md.png" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-lg-2">
        <img src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/f/5/6/f/1352194206656819167small_ragdoll_kitten-md.png" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-lg-2">
        <img src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/f/5/6/f/1352194206656819167small_ragdoll_kitten-md.png" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-lg-2">
        <img src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/f/5/6/f/1352194206656819167small_ragdoll_kitten-md.png" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-lg-2">
        <img src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/f/5/6/f/1352194206656819167small_ragdoll_kitten-md.png" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-lg-2">
        <img src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/f/5/6/f/1352194206656819167small_ragdoll_kitten-md.png" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-lg-2">
        <img src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/f/5/6/f/1352194206656819167small_ragdoll_kitten-md.png" />
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

JQuery

```
$('.slider').slick({
  centerMode: true,
  centerPadding: '60px',
  slidesToShow: 9,
   adaptiveHeight: true,
  responsive: [
    {
      breakpoint: 768,
      settings: {
        arrows: false,
        centerMode: true,
        centerPadding: '40px',
        slidesToShow: 3
      }
    },
    {
      breakpoint: 480,
      settings: {
        arrows: false,
        centerMode: true,
        centerPadding: '40px',
        slidesToShow: 2
      }
    }
  ]
});
```

The slickjs worked as expected, but I couldn't find a way to disable slick in laptop and desktop sizes. How to disable slick when in laptop and desktop sizes?

Also, when in mobile size, how to enable slick and also show 9 thumbnails in 2 rows per slide ( 9 x 2 slides) (not one slide row with all 18 thumbnails)? Thought that increasing height would help but apparently not.

Help appreciated.

Comment: I had a similar problem and suggest you to use this little plugin http://wicky.nillia.ms/enquire.js/ to handle your changes to the slick slider. You basically call the slickJS each time on a media query but with different settings (the ones you wish)! Enquire JS makes it possible to call JS on each breakpoint.

Comment: @supersize hmm what about 9 x 2 thumbnails? does enquirejs also make it possible? What about disabling slick?

Comment: there is a div with `id="slick-track"`. This contains all your thumbs and has a width calculated by the number of thumbnails * width of one thumbnail (including margins). If you go into the source code and devide this width by 2 then remove the `float:left` from `.slick-slide ` and add `display:inline-block; height:125px` <- half of .slick-track height you see two rows. This is very complicated though and challanging to make it responsive to browser width.

Comment: @EdwinKrause - woah, it is a bit overwhelming ha. I was hoping that slickjs would do a job but I guess not :(

Comment: @joe have a look at: http://jsfiddle.net/rzJq9/78/ I think this should help you. It illustrates how to make more rows within one track. Basically you need to float the divs that they break into a new line. I wouldn't use Boostrap within the slickJS anyway. It overcomplicates things!

Comment: @supersize - thanks for making it less complicated! Then I will remove Bootstrap. So with enquirejs, enable slickjs when mobile size right? btw your fiddle doesn't slide? Just wondering.

Comment: @joe the fiddle works fine for me. I will provide an answer for the enquireJS bit.

Comment: @supersize - weird I can't slide the example. Thanks for enquireJS answer in advance :)

Comment: @supersize - sorry and I have tried your example, but it doesn't work too well with my faces images, it is like scattering even with row or container. hmm. can you please give me a sample example if using enquire for thumb you mentioned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [enquire.js](http://wicky.nillia.ms/enquire.js/) for the more advanced responsive bit, where you recall your [slickJS](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) carousel with the options you want it for:

```
enquire.register("(max-width: 768px)", {

  match : function() {
    $('.slider').slick({ /* your options for smaller screens than 768px */ });
  },      


  unmatch : function() {
    $('.slider').slick({ /* your options for bigger screens than 768px */ });
  }

});
```

in this example you recall the slider on mobile devices with a `max-width` of `768px`. You have to put your options in, how many slides you want to have, for example:

```
$('.slider').slick({
    slidesToShow: 4,
    slidesToScroll: 4
});
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks! One more question, unmatch - how to disable slick? I remember i see 'unslick' setting. Unslick: true, it works right? Because I tried it for test, it didn't do anything.

Comment: @joe the `unslick` method does not need any arguments which is why you can simply do `$('.slider').slick('unslick');`!

Comment: oh I see. thanks! :) I will work on this tomorrow or monday and if im still struggling i will ask again. thanks